# rich:editor formatting

Tags: richfaces

I am using rich:editor to create the content in my application.
I am storing the content data in a string property in backend bean and persisting it into database using hibernate.
The problem is whenever i am applying any formatting style it is alos coming up with the content and  stored into database.
i want to save the data in html formate and view it again in rich:modalpanel.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

eg. You can use

```
  h:outputText value="#{question.qText}" escape="false"
```

The value="#{question.qText}" is text stored as html :). and escape="false" does the rest.

Comment: Hi Sugandha..my content is saving in database like this: [color=#ff0000][b]content[/b][/color] if i am writing "content" in text editor and applying some style on that text.after using escape at the time of displaying i didn't get the desired result.i want that my datab will be saved in html format after applying style to text but this is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hey this is my code for test case :
```

**rich:editor id="editor"  width="525" height="260" value="#{bean.qText}" theme="advanced"
rich:editor**

and the result is

Science is ........................... .

for science red bold

> :: possibly you are using seam

useSeamText="true"
[This link might be helpful](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.1.5.GA/reference/en/html/text.html)